# Super wildcard with consumer function

Tags: java, function, wildcard

I can't find an answer so...
I have read the post [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) and understood that instance of `List<? super Number>` can return only `Object` type and that is true.
But if I try to use a super wildcard with `Consumer` like this

```
Consumer<? super Number> consumerNum = n -> System.out.println("number " + (n.intValue() + 200));
```

Variable n is `Number` not `Object`!
Why?
I can't understand.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that type-inference allows that! I would have guessed that the compiler would complain that it can't tell what the lambda's type should be. (But if the compiler is going to accept it, `Number` definitely seems to make more sense than `Object`. Can you clarify why you expect the latter?)

Comment: Because of the following:  What type of object are you guaranteed to receive when you read from `List<? super Integer> foo3`: 1) You aren't guaranteed an `Integer` because `foo3` could be pointing at a `List<Number>` or `List<Object>`. 2) You aren't guaranteed a `Number` because `foo3` could be pointing at a `List<Object>`. 3) The only guarantee is that you will get an instance of an `Object` or subclass of `Object` (but you don't know what subclass).

Comment: In addition to distinguishing a *consumer* from a *list*, you also need to distinguish the code that *fulfills* the contract from the code that *relies on* the contract. Note that `Consumer<? super Number> consumer = numberConsumer` is totally valid when `numberConsumer` implements `Consumer<Number>`, because `Number` *is* a supertype of `Number`.